# State is being deleted in React JS

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I'm new to React. I'm trying to make a todo app, but every time when I update state, (I want to change some bool values), it gets deleted. Please, can someone explain, what is going on in my code, why it's not deleted in function `todoDoneParent`. Code:

**TodoApp** component

```
class TodoApp extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {id: 1, body: 'First Todo', isDone: false},
      {id: 2, body: 'Second Todo', isDone: false},
      {id: 3, body: 'Third Todo', isDone: false}
    ]
  }
  todoDoneParent= (id) => {
    let copyState = [...this.state.todos];
    let todo = copyState.filter(todo => todo.id == id );
    todo[0].isDone = true;
    let todos = copyState.filter(todo => todo.id != id );
    this.setState({ todos: todo, todos }); 

    console.log('INSIDE todoDoneParent', this.state.todos);///////////////////////////////FIRST PRINT
  }
  render() {
    console.log('INSIDE TodoApp.render()', this.state.todos); ///////////////////////////////SECOND PRINT
    return (
      <div className="allTodos">
      <Todos allTodos={this.state.todos} todoDoneParent={this.todoDoneParent}></Todos>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Todos** component

```
class Todos extends Component {
  todoDone = (e) => {
    this.props.todoDoneParent(e.target.id);
  }
  render(){
    const todos= this.props.allTodos;
    const list = todos.length ? (
      todos.map(todo => {
        if(todo.isDone === false){
          return(<div className='todo' key={todo.id}>
            <div className='todo-container'>
              <div>
                <p>{todo.body}</p>
              </div>
              <button className='btn' id={todo.id} onClick={this.todoDone}>
                Done
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>)
        }
      })
    ) : (
      <div>
        <p>No todos</p>
      </div>
    );
    return(
      <div className='content'> 
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Outputs** (in Console)

*When it's just rendered*

```
INSIDE TodoApp.render() 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, body: "First Todo", isDone: false}
1: {id: 2, body: "Second Todo", isDone: false}
2: {id: 3, body: "Third Todo", isDone: false}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

*When I clicked any button*

```
INSIDE todoDoneParent
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, body: "First Todo", isDone: false}
1: {id: 2, body: "Second Todo", isDone: false}
2: {id: 3, body: "Third Todo", isDone: true}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

INSIDE TodoApp.render() 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, body: "First Todo", isDone: false}
1: {id: 2, body: "Second Todo", isDone: false}
length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```

So why when I click the button ```Done``` , it updates the state well inside ```todoDoneParent``` function, but, when it is going to be rendered, those state that I updated, gets deleted?

Comment: `this.setState({ todos: todo, todos });` just overwrites `this.state.todos` with the `todos` that filtered out the one you wanted to mark done. What are you expecting the function to do?

Comment: @DrewReese I want this function to update the  ```isDone```  variable to ```true```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`this.setState({ todos: todo, todos });` just overwrites `this.state.todos` with the `todos` that filtered out the one you wanted to mark done. It removes it from the `todos` array.

Another issue is a type comparison issue where the `id` type of your todos is "number", but the `id` field coming back from the `onClick` event is type "string". `===` uses type equality, i.e. `5 === '5'` is false, but `5 == '5'`.

## Solution

If I understand correctly that you simply want to toggle the `isDone` property of a specific todo to `true` then you should map the old `todos` to the new `todos` and update the specific todo when the `id` matches.

TodoApp

```
todoDoneParent = (id) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    todos: prevState.todos.map((todo) =>
      todo.id === id
        ? {
            ...todo,
            isDone: true
          }
        : todo
    )
  }));
};
```

Todos

Convert the `id` value back to a number type for the comparison in the parent component.

```
todoDone = (e) => {
  const { id } = e.target;
  this.props.todoDoneParent(Number(id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not updating anything, where could there be a mistake? in my code I mean.

Comment: @mecdeality `===` does a strict type comparison, i.e. `5 === '5'` is false, but `5 == '5'` is true, i.e. '==' attempts to do type coercion for the comparison. The `id` of the task is typeof "number", but `e.target.id` is typeof "string", so the `todo.id === id` condition is always `false` and nothing gets updated.. You can force it back to a number: `this.props.todoDoneParent(Number(e.target.id));` and then the `===` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Change inside of `todoDoneParent` to this, this will work. You just have to map over the todos and updated the todo and have to return new list.

```
todoDoneParent= (id) => {
  const updatedState = this.state.todos.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      return {
        ...item,
        isDone: true
      }
    }
    return item;
  });
  this.setState({ todos: updatedState });
}
```